# Cocoapods Error at Compile time

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

Why am I getting this error when I try to compile my app after installing `AFNetworking` using `Cocoapods`?

```
/Users/adsfa/Documents/adfasf/Pods/Pods-resources.sh: line 5: 
/Users/asdfa/Documents/sounasdfafdme/Pods/resources-to-copy-Krafdsakfen.txt: Permission denied
```

My Podfile:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
```

however, when I try to do `open Podfile`, I receive this

```
/Users/me/Documents/soundme/Podfile ; exit;
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0) among 110 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
logout

[Process completed]
```

Comment: include podfile details

Comment: @LithuT.V edited above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the version of ruby and rails running in the machine and make sure cocoapod is installed in the same

To see all the installed gems in the current version

```
gem list
```

Comment: I'm using rvm, so when I type in rvm version I get
rvm 1.25.19

Comment: not sure how to check which version of ruby cocoapods is using

Comment: `ruby -v` in terminal