# cocoapod setup/install error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

When I run `pod setup` and `pod install`

I receive the following error:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0) among 109 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
    from /Users/dereklo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

yet when I run sudo pod setup and sudo pod install it seems to work:

```
sudo pod setup
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
Updating 4974084..a1c1bb3

Fast-forward

 Heyzap/6.4.0/Heyzap.podspec | 20 ++++++++++++++++++++

 1 file changed, 20 insertions(+)

 create mode 100755 Heyzap/6.4.0/Heyzap.podspec
From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs

   4974084..a1c1bb3  master     -> origin/master
Setup completed (read-only access)
```

And

```
sudo pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (2.2.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] From now on use `adsfasdf.xcworkspace`.
```

Why is this?

Comment: its ok, try `open adsfasdf.xcworkspace` and let me know

Comment: @preetam I get "Pods project” is locked for editing and you may not be able to save your changes. Do you want to unlock it?" and then this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241797/cocoapods-error-at-compile-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way to try by removing your POD Master...

A. `pod repo remove master`

then repeat the pod set up...

B. `pod setup`

C.  Install pods for your projects.